# wait for Promise.all in a synchronous function, basically blocking! javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, synchronization, es6-promise

I have alot of syncrhounous functions that i want to execute before that are basic ajax requests, these request will render html to the DOM.

In order to do this i had to execute all of this synchrounous 
requests one by one. But i somehow want to these synchrounous functions asynchrounous all at the same time and wait for them to finnish in order to speed things up. This has to happen inside a synchrounous function. But my understanding is that this doesnt work in javascript, but i would like to hear what you guys have to say.

So my attempt was to add all of these synchrounous requests into asynchrounous promises and then do a Promise.all call. I cant wait for the promise.all().then because the main thread will keep on execute the rest of the code after this main synchrounous thread/function. So i wonder if there is a way to block the main thread in order to wait for these asynchrounous calls

heres a short illustration of what im talking about

```
var syncfunc = () => {
var getPromise = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var asyncAjaxRequest = async function() {
            doSomeStuff();
            resolve();
        }
    })
}
var promises = [getPromse(), getPromse(), getPromse()];


Promise.all(promises);

console.log('i want this console.log to execute after all promises executed doSomeStuff');

/**
 * 
 * Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        // I cant use this, because its script in other files that will execute if i wait like this
    })
 */
}
```

I know .then will execute when all resolves are done, but i basiacally want  to block this synchrounous thread waiting for all other asynchrounous to finish.

If i could i would ofcourse change the structure into my needs, but the problem and the reason why im trying to do this is because im using sitevision framework, and want to add some content to the dom before a print module opens the print window. To call every function synchrounous is just not the way to go, its to slow. Ive also tried to set window.print = null to make the print function disabled, and then add the print function back when promises resolves, but it simply doesnt work

Comment: You cannot make asynchronous functions synchronous.

Comment: yeah thats why i thought, so there is no way i could solve my problem?

Comment: @HermanJansson: There might be but we don't have enough information to make a suggestion. For example, the obvious solution is to move "everything after that line" into the `.then` callback.

Comment: What's the actual reason why you won't do `Promise.all(promises).then(() => { console.log(); });` ? Because that's the solution...

Comment: Could you not make an asynchronous function call that which calls all the ajax request promises. Then call await on the initial function

Comment: @DerekLawrence the problem is that i cant use await in a synchrounous function, which is the function that i will call Promise.all() in

Comment: @HermanJansson you have to think of another way. Javascript is incapable of doing what you're asking.

Comment: There is basically never a reason why you cannot rearrange your code so that you control when it's executed. E.g. you can put all code in a function and call the function whenever you want.

Comment: If the function is synchronous and it has to stay synchronous because other functions are calling it and expecting it to be synchronous, well then too bad, you'll just have to go into every place that calls the function and make them asynchronous or work with .then() too.

Comment: Maybe this helps, even though it doesn't quite address your issue: https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html

Comment: @TKoL yeah i assumed that, because im working on a framework, which will execute other scripts if i dont wait for these calls, and these calls has to be executed before in order for it to work. I cant decide when these scripts will execute, since its part of the framework, so they will execute direcly after :)

Comment: You'll just have to find another way. I suspect there is one though.

Comment: What exactly does this mean (wrt framework)? You mentioned that this code is inside a function. Does this function have to return something synchronously? Is that what you mean? If not, please provide a better example that demonstrates the issue you have, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: @Felix Kling Im trying retrieve some information on another website before a print module in sitevision is used, this module will open print window, i have to render the content before this print window opens, and to do all calls sync takes to long time, because there plenty of them

Answer (score 4):

You cannot make an asynchronous operation turn into a synchronous one in plain Javascript (without external code).  The event driven JS engine just doesn't work that way.

By definition, an asynchronous operation starts the operation (handing execution off to native code) and then returns back to the interpreter which then continues to execute the code that follows.  The native code will add an event to JS event queue when it finishes to allow the interpreter event loop to service the completion of the asynchronous operation.  If you were the create some sort of "block" such as a semi-infinite while loop, that would "block" the interpreter from executing more code, you end up in a stalemate.  The loop that is blocking the interpreter prevents the JS interpreter from ever getting to the point where it can ever process the event that signals the end of the asynchronous operation.  So, you have a loop waiting for something to finish, but the thing it's waiting for can't finish until the loop finishes - stalemate.

So, because of the single threaded event loop nature of the JS interpreter, you can't (purely in Javascript) block waiting for the end of an asynchronous operation.

Pretty much always, the correct design is to refactor the surrounding code/infrastructure to work with an asynchronous operation and asynchronous result (callback or promise).

---

If this is node.js, there are a couple of horrific hacks that can get you this result, but they block the entire interpreter so are almost never a desired design.

The first option involves writing a custom nodejs plugin (async operations done in native code) that provides a blocking interface that just doesn't return until the operation is done.

The second option involves using the [synchronous child_process operations](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_synchronous_process_creation) (such as `child_process.execFileSync()` to create a blocking child process, run your code in that child process and then continue when that process finishes.

Both I could consider pretty bad hacks and pretty much never the desired way to solve such a problem.  But, I did want to show you what has to be done in order to block for an asynchronous operation (it has to be moved out of Javascript or out of the process).

---

If you can't figure out how to solve your real problem with non-blocking, asynchronous operations, I'd suggest you post a new question where you describe in detail exactly what the real problem is and we can help you find an asynchronous design that would work for your situation.  If you post a link to the new question in a comment here, some of the people engaged here may check in on the new question and attempt to help.

Answer (score -5):

You could use async/await to solve this. This is how you do it:

```
async function promiseSolver() {
var getPromise = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var asyncAjaxRequest = async function() {
            doSomeStuff();
            resolve();
        }
    })
}
var promises = [getPromse(), getPromse(), getPromse()];


await Promise.all(promises);

console.log('i want this console.log to execute after all promises executed doSomeStuff');

/**
 * 
 * Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        // I cant use this, because its script in other files that will execute if i wait like this
    })
 */
}
```

Basically, your code will wait until the .all is completed and then will continue with processing. Take into consideration that while the code execution is synchronous, the code will be non blocking.